# Saving Image via Web Service to SQL and Retrieving It

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql

I have created a Web Service that is intended to receive an image from a 3rd party, which will then gets imported into a SQL table.
After that, I retrieve the image and save it to a directory from an Azure Database at my end.

Everything works and I receive no errors, except when I retrieve the image into a 'test' picturebox, I get a 'Red X' for the image which signify's an error with the image.

Is anyone able to look at my code and see what I am doing wrong? This is the first time for me doing this kind of stuff.

Web Service:

```vb
Public Function Wunelli_SendImage(ByVal PolicyRef As String, ByVal ImagePath As String) Implements FreshCloud.Wunelli_SendImage  
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(sqlConn)
        'SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Autosaint_Wunelli_Engineer_Images] VALUES(@policyref,GETDATE(),@photo)", cn)
            Try
                With cmd
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@policyref", "LYJX01PC01")

                    Using MS As New MemoryStream(), BM As New Bitmap(ImagePath)
                        BM.Save(MS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                        Dim data As Byte() = MS.GetBuffer()
                        Dim p As New SqlParameter("@photo", SqlDbType.Image)
                        p.Value = data
                        .Parameters.Add(p)
                    End Using

                    .Connection.Open()

                    Return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    .Connection.Close()
                End With
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message & " " & ex.StackTrace)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

WPF Test Harness to Retrieve Image:

```vb
Try
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(sqlConn)
        'SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT [Image] From [dbo].[Autosaint_Wunelli_Engineer_Images] WHERE [PolicyRef] = 'LYJX01PC01'", cn)
            Try
                With cmd
                    .Connection.Open()
                    Dim imageData As Byte() = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

                    If Not imageData Is Nothing Then
                        Using ms As New MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
                            ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
                            PictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
                        End Using
                    End If

                    .Connection.Close()

                End With

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message & " " & ex.StackTrace)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message & " " & ex.StackTrace)
End Try
```

Comment: Regarding the `SendImage` method: **1)** Don't use `Parameters.AddWithValue`, instead create the param and give it an explicit datatype, just like with `@photo`, **2)** do not use the `IMAGE` datatype if using SQL Server 2005 or newer, either in the DB or in this app code via `SqlDbType.Image`, instead use `VARBINARY(MAX)` in the DB and here use `SqlParameter("@photo", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1)` where `-1` means `MAX`, **3)** you don't need `MemoryStream` or `Bitmap`, instead use `p.Value = File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath)` and not waste memory, **4)** `INSERT` statement should include field names.

Comment: srutzky, can you put your response back as an answer so I can give it a tick please :), I took the advice from you both and have a result! :)

Comment: answer has been posted  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`Image.FromStream` docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kcb3wy4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

So, change this:

```
Using ms As New MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
```

to

```
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length)
```

and remove the `End Using`, so that the stream is not disposed, and it should work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `Wunelli_SendImage` method:

1. Don't use `Parameters.AddWithValue`. Instead, create the parameter explicitly and give it a datatype, just like with `@photo`.
2. Do not use the `IMAGE` datatype if using SQL Server 2005 or newer, either in the DB or in this app code via `SqlDbType.Image`. Instead, use `VARBINARY(MAX)` in the DB and here use `SqlParameter("@photo", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1)` where `-1` equates to `MAX`.
3. You don't need to create the `MemoryStream` or `Bitmap` objects. Instead, use `p.Value = File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath)` and not waste memory, or at least get rid of some unnecessary steps.
4. The `INSERT` statement should include the field names:
   `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Autosaint_Wunelli_Engineer_Images] ([PolicyRef], [Date], [Image]) VALUES (@policyref, GETDATE(), @photo);`